# Why some of the android apps doesn't work on Wifi

Tags: wi-fi

Why some of my android apps doesn't work on Wifi when all other apps work fine.

And these apps work on Mobile Data but not on my Home wifi.

> These apps work when I switch 'Airplane Mode - On' and turn On my Wifi

**Tried:**

1. Have tried searching this on [XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1120013)
2. Tried Static IP instead of DHCP
3. Setting my time and date manually
4. Checked my App Data Usage (for specific app) - 1.66Mb over Wifi & 11.02Mb over Mobile data
5. Tried my Wifi password twice, tried rebooting my phone twice.
6. Tried App Restrictions & Storage Permissions
7. Turned Power Saving Mode - Off

**FYI:**

My app is in Testing phase - Loading Bitmaps

My Phone is Coolpad3600I ver: 6.0.1

Couldn't understand this weird problem. Need help.

Comment: Didi you check the Logcat and troubleshoot the app?

Comment: Thanks @esQmo_ I forgot to mention, when I tested it on other phone Huawei 4.4.2 wifi was working fine, and it was loading the bitmaps as expected. Logcat was showing lot of messages since I was using Firebase to load bitmaps, nothing was shown which was wifi or data related - so I was quite sure, the problem is device specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research yesterday, I found my project was lacking few crucial steps for loading bitmaps

- Caching of bitmaps was not properly implemented because of which I was getting Out of Memory errors
- I was also getting Android Support Disable plugin error after every few minutes
- Android Profile Analyzer was showing lot of irrelevant threads which was consuming memory

Since, I didn't have much time to look in every file of my code. I modified my sluggish code and imported *Android Bitmap Sample* code from the library.

Most of the common errors of Wifi, caching of bitmaps & Disable Plugin errors were taken care.